# Spring Boot: adding another WAR files to the embedded tomcat

Tags: spring, tomcat

I'm trying to add foo.war to spring boot application with embedded tomcat. But I have a conflict with classes from spring boot application, seems classes are loaded from foo.war and application. I'd like to use only classes from foo.war

```
@Bean
public EmbeddedServletContainerFactory servletContainerFactory() {
    return new TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory() {

    @Override
    protected TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer getTomcatEmbeddedServletContainer(
            Tomcat tomcat) {
        try {
            Context context = tomcat.addWebapp("/foo", "/path/to/foo.war");
        } catch (ServletException ex) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("Failed to add webapp", ex);
        }
        return super.getTomcatEmbeddedServletContainer(tomcat);
    }

};
}
```